# Why does percentage height work on position fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I've learned that percentage height only works if the parent (and parents) elements all has `height` value set. But why that is not required on a `position:fixed` element.

```css
div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div>placeholder</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`position: fixed` is relative to the screen's viewport and ignores parent elements' positioning.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> **fixed**
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, [`height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property) percentages don't work if the parent has the initial `height: auto`.

That's because `height` percentages are resolved with respect to the height of the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block). But if the block ancestor which establishes the containing block has `height: auto`, its height will be the height of its contents.

That would be a circular definition, so the percentage is treated as `auto`.

However, this problem is avoided with [absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) (including [fixed one](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)). Absolutely positioned elements are taken [out-of-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23), so they have no impact on the height of block ancestors with `height: auto`. In that case it's no longer a circular definition, so it works.

This is explained in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block). If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.